# Write Values from Checkbox to Text File and Count the Minimum and Maximum Selected Values

Tags: c#, count, text-files, max, checkboxlist

After I do this it's not doing anything that I want to do or otherwise, it writes twice to the file in one line.

The code bellow try to write a value from check box into a text file then find the maximum and minimum value.

```
List<string> myLs = new List<string>();
            int checke = 0;

            foreach (ListItem item in coursess.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    checke = checke + 1;

                }
            }
            if (checke < 4)
            {
                kk.Text = "less";
                kk.Visible = true;
            }
            else if (checke > 6)
            {
                kk.Text = "More";
                kk.Visible = true;
            }
            else if(checke == 4 || checke == 5 || checke == 6)
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in coursess.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                    {
                        myLs.Add(item.Value);
                    }
                }
                String datas = String.Join(",", myLs.ToArray());
```

Comment: no idea what your question is, but you should just add to `myLs` in your first foreach

Comment: then it will add the values before checking the number of selected items

Comment: from the code you have posted that doesn't seem to matter? could you explain what your problem is?

Comment: I want to select items from a checkbox list and if the selected checkbox are less than four or high than 6 then it should print an error message, if the selected check box are more than or equal to 4 and less than or equal to 6 then it should write those values from a checkbox to a text file im doing in C# and aspx

Comment: Please help if you can

Comment: right.. if I've understood your question right.. `coursess` is your checkbox list and you want to write the selected items to a file.. 
so instead of the `checke` int you can just add the `myLs` when an item is selected, then check set checke to the `myLs.count` after searching through them. then instead of adding to myLs again, just use a `streamwriter` to write myLs to a file..

Comment: I did as you told me and it worked!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it looks like a message will be displayed when less than four or more than six checkboxes are checked.  As for writing the string to a file, how about something like this at the end...

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\selectedcourses.txt", datas);
```

This should write the entire string, once, to the path that you choose.

Comment: But its not displaying any message

Comment: I copied your code into a Web Forms application, and it does display the "less" and "More" messages for me.  I'm doing this in a button click event handler, and kk is a Label.  Is that how you have it set up?